# How to adjust cards with different image size but keep cards size

Tags: sass, ionic2

I have svg images which each has different sizes, but the end result that I"m looking for, is, same card size for all cards, and the remaining space - give it to the image.

The image should fill the height with the remaining height, the width can stay "auto" **OR** image with 50px for example but have it `vertical-align: middle` it ( the Ionic helpers doesn't work here .. )

I have this stackblitz example: https://ionic-qdmmmw.stackblitz.io

#### home.ts

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic 2 - cards with different img size but same card size</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-row>  
   <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-card style="border: green 2px solid;">
    <img 
      style="height: 40px; width: auto;"
      src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
    <ion-card-content style="padding: 0; background-color: yellow;">
      <ion-card-title style="background-color: red">
        Nine Inch Nails Live
        </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        The most popular industrial group ever, and largely
        responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
   </ion-col>

   <ion-col col-4>
  <ion-card style="border: green 2px solid;">
    <img 
      style="height: 20px; width: auto;"
      src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>
    <ion-card-content style="padding: 0; background-color: yellow;">
      <ion-card-title style="background-color: red;">
        Nine Inch Nails Live
        </ion-card-title>
      <p>
        The most popular industrial group ever, and largely
        responsible for bringing the music to a mass audience.
      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
   </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Couple of issues I have with the example above:

- The footer( `ion-card-title` ) is not sticked to the bottom ( when fixing the cards with with setting the `ion-col` with `style='display: flex'`
- Image size affect card size

Tried many things, but still didn't get the right results ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic2-cards-with-different-image-size-but-keep-cards-height)

```css
ion-content {
  ion-col {
    display: flex;
  }
}

ion-card {
  img {
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 25vh !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width: 85%;
    align-items: center;
  }
  ion-card-content {
    padding: 0 !important;
    ion-card-title {
      padding-top: 1.5rem !important;
      padding-bottom: 1.5rem !important;
    }
  }
}
```